# jquery xml attribute returning undefined

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

I can't figure this out and been messing with it for a while now.

XML:

```
<page name="bio">
<image imageUrl="img/bio.png" link="#"/>
<texts>
<pageText><![CDATA[blah
]]></pageText>
</texts>
</page>
```

jQuery

```
$.get('../tfile_main.xml', function(xml){
$varbioimg = $(xml).find('page[name="bio"] image');
alert($varbioimg.attr('imageUrl'));
});
```

this returns undefined for some reason , I also tried to find('page[name="bio"] > image')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [`.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), using jQuery's css selectors to parse xml is not recommended

```
var xml = '<page name="bio"><image imageUrl="img/bio.png" link="#"/><texts><pageText><![CDATA[blah]]></pageText></texts></page>';

xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
$xml = $( xmlDoc );    
console.log($xml.find('page[name="bio"] image'));
```

here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/FVHEU/

Comment: thanks, can parseXML() be used with an external xml file though?

Comment: if that file is read by the server and sent as `xml` to the client side then yes it can be used on the external file...

Answer (score 0):

While I second using `.parseXML`, I also have to mention that your original example worked for me. Make sure that your XML file exactly matches what you've posted here (with the addition of `<?xml version="1.0">` at the top) and navigate to the URL of the XML file with Firefox; it will let you know if there are any parsing errors.